# MySQL show status

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a row count of `48769914`. The problem is the bogus information when querying the database, i.e., the data_length. Any ideas on how to correct this misbehavior?

```
mysql> show table status like "events"\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: events
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 32768
      Data_free: 7405043712
 Auto_increment: 59816602
    Create_time: 2012-06-05 05:12:37
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.88 sec)
```

exact count:

```
mysql> select count(id) from events;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|  48769914 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (5 min 37.67 sec)
```

**Update** The status information looks like the table was empty. Zero rows, zero row length and basically no data in the table. How can I get MySQL to show correct estimates for that data.

Comment: I want to know why `show status` returns useless information or rather how to get useful data

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB row count is not precise, because InnoDB does not keep track of records count internally, it can only estimate this by amount of allocated space in the tablespace.

See [InnoDB restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) in the manual for more information

Comment: That is the problem. Zero is not a very good approximation for 48769914, setting aside the other data for the table, e.g., data_length.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB doesn't store row count in the table status so that isn't bogus. You solve this by running your `SELECT` query where you want the row count.